# How to get ChildFragmentManager inside a Fragment that inflate's a ViewPager with Fragments

Tags: android

Here is how my hierarchy looks like:

```
MainActivity -> Fragment -> Dialog -> ViewPager -> Fragment 1, 2, 3
```

Getting the SupportFragmentManager works by casting:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

However I can't seem to get the ChildFragmentManager.

```
((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getChildFragmentManager()
```

is not valid.

Comment: Only Fragments have a `childFragmentManager`, why are you trying to get one from the activity?

Comment: I'm trying to get one from the Dialog because I am inflating my PagerAdapter there ```MainPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);```

Comment: Are you using a `DialogFragment` to display your `Dialog`?

Comment: No just regular dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular dialog doesn't have a `FragmentManager`, so you could not add a Fragment based `ViewPager` inside of it.

Instead, you should use a `DialogFragment` as per the [Dialogs documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) and override its `onCreateDialog()` to create your `Dialog`. In a `DialogFragment`, you can use `getChildFragmentManager()` with a ViewPager.

Comment: But DialogFragment covers the whole screen, I want the dialog size. And also the background isn't Dark when the dialog fragment is inflated

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using `show()` to show your dialog. You can put your exact code you use for your `Dialog` in `onCreateDialog()`.

Comment: Yes you are correct I was manually inflating it. Thanks for your help!